# How to make gitignore exclude a specific js file present in 2 folders, whereas ignoring all other js files?

Tags: git, gitignore

File Structure:

- Root

  - Folder1

    - file.js
    - more files
  - Folder2

    - file.js
    - more files
  - .gitignore

I want to ignore all .js files except file.js(which is present in both folders with same name). So, in my gitignore, I tried the following:

Option 1:

```
!*file.js
*.js
```

Option 2:

```
!/*/file.js
*.js
```

Option 3:

```
!/Folder1/file.js
!/Folder2/file.js
*.js
```

But always only the file.js in Folder1 is included with all 3 options, and file.js in Folder2 is always ignored. Other js files in both folders are ignored perfectly. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Ignore rules are taken *in the order they appear*, so `*.js` overrides the previous `!`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the global `*.js` at the top. By putting *.js at the bottom it overrides the excludes above it.

```
*.js
!Folder1/file.js
!Folder2/file.fs
```

Comment: The leading `/` is immaterial in this particular case. It can be present or absent with no change because of the embedded (non-trailing) `/`.

Comment: Good to know. The placement of the `*.js` was the real issue.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Although still confused, as earlier I had a single folder, and then putting *.js below the exclusion didn't affect anything.